# Textbook definition for "path measure" or "probability measure over paths"

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I need a formal definition for the path measure for stochastic differential equations.

Which textbook or paper should I consult?

Comment: one Wiener measure and path integrals reference is "Quantum Physics: a Functional Integral Point of View" from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255578/schwartz-space-gaussian-measures-and-integration-over-paths?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

since I don't see any other answers, I will turn my comment into answer.

One Wiener measure and path integrals reference is "Quantum Physics: a Functional Integral Point of View" from here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255578/schwartz-space-gaussian-measures-and-integration-over-paths?rq=1

For more references in the context of regularity structures and functional integration, see here:

Some interesting series of works on the connection between the two are:

- Regularity structures applied to stochastic quantization, whose goal is to make sense of these functional integrals eg. ["Regularity structures and the dynamical $\Phi^4_3$ model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05261)"
- Regularity structures applied to random loops where again we end up with a problem of making sense of an invariant measure eg. ["Rough Stochastic PDEs"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1708) and see main conjecture 4.5 in ["Geometric stochastic heat equations"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.02884)